# Oracle SQL Stored Procedure with Oracle reserved words passed to variable

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, stored-procedures, reserved-words

I have a stored procedure that gets passed a string of values separated with spaces, which then does a search in the table and returns data where a column has any of those values. All went well until a user needed to pass 'INDEX END UNKNOWN PROCESS' which didn't return anything, even though there is data with those values:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  Searches
(
   QUEUE             IN TYPES.CHAR50,  
   P_CURSOR          IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  
)   
AS

BEGIN

OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
 SELECT *
 FROM tablez t
 WHERE /* If the subquery returns UNKNOWN, END, PROCESS, INDEX which are Oracle reserved words the main query won't return any results */
       /* In order to pass this inconsistency, I concatenated XYZ to both sides when using IN Clause                                   */
       CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(t.QUEUECD)),'XYZ') IN ( SELECT CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(tr.prom)),'XYZ')     
                                                        FROM ( SELECT regexp_substr(QUEUE,'[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) prom 
                                                               FROM dual 
                                                               CONNECT BY regexp_substr(QUEUE, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL 
                                                              ) tr   
                                                       )
    ;

END Searches;
```

So, I changed the code to use regexp_substr, and only concatenating 'XYZ' returned values when doing the comparison. But this is a temporary fix, because QUEUECD is an indexed column in the database and using CONCAT in WHERE clause led to performance issues, on big data. 
Do you have any suggestions how to improve the performance or pass the list of values in a different way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Oracle SQL Stored Procedure with Oracle reserved words passed to
>   variable

It looks like a different problem. Look: there is no way to pass "reserved words" as a value of variable - when you've got varchar variable then the value is a text - nothing more.

I've made a sample table and tested a query without concatenation 'XYZ' - and I don't have such problems. Maybe there are some white, non-printable characters at the end or beginning in records??

Regarding to:

> Do you have any suggestions how to improve the performance or pass the list of values in a different way?

Yes. Pass collection (nested table) as parameter. For example:

```
create or replace type T_TAB_STRING as table of varchar2(4000);
```

Next, change type of QUEUE from `TYPES.CHAR50` to `T_TAB_STRING`.

Then you can use table() expression to unnest collection inside query like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablez t
WHERE t.QUEUECD IN ( SELECT /*+ DYNAMIC_SAMPLING(tr, 2) */
                         *
                       FROM TABLE(QUEUE) tr
                   )
;
```

The dynamic sampling hint is for forcing DB to check how many elements is inside collection. Without that DB assume it is the size of 1 block (usually 8k), so CBO could choose to do full scan instead of index scan.

If you cannot use that hint, or it doesn't work for some reason, there is other way to help CBO with collections in queries. It's implementing Extensible Optimiser interface for that collection. It has been written by Adrian Billington in [this article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=427) how to do it.

Comment: Thank you robertus. This data has been recently converted from DB2 to Oracle and yes, a lot of data has trailing/leading spaces. I'll give it a try without concat and just check if the trimming should work. I have to check if I have enough access to use your performance improvement ideas. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the DYNAMIC_SAMPLING function is not activated for our database and we are not allowed to use it.

Comment: [There is](http://www.oracle-developer.net/content/utilities/ccard.sql) really good example how to implement  Extensible Optimiser Interface for nested table type. Without  Extensible Optimiser Interface or dynamic sampling hint do not use collections in queries directly - usually it will be slow.